# PhpStorm Git folder modified color

Tags: git, version-control, phpstorm

My PhpStorm is coloring changed files when a project is under Git, I want to color the folder also so I can notice that there is a file changed under that colored folder.

Thanks.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You will have to enable the following option: `Settings (Preferences on Mac) | Version Control | Show directories with changed descendants`

**UPDATE 2021-12-27:**

Nowadays (PhpStorm 2021.3) this option has a bit different name `Highlight directories that contain modified files in the Project tree` and lives at `Settings/Preferences | Version Control | Confirmation` settings screen.

[image]