# How to show blue dot icons when files were modified with Git in PhpStorm?

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, phpstorm

How to show blue dot icons when files were modified with Git in PhpStorm IDE like this picture?

[image: I want to display blue dot icons in the right when editing files]

Please help me setup for this in PhpStorm IDE. Thank you so much.

Comment: Where that screenshot is from?

Comment: @LazyOne This is from sublime text

Comment: Well, PhpStorm (and other IDEA-based IDEs) do not have such dots. Colors are used to specify the VCS status. 1) Default colors and their meaning can be seen here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/project-tool-window.html#file_status_highlight  2) You can see and change those colors at `Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Version Control | File Status Colors`

Comment: @LazyOne Thank you very much. That is very helpful for me. Have a good day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PhpStorm (and other IDEA-based IDEs) does not have such dots. Instead the file name color is used to specify the VCS file status.

1. Default colors and their meaning can be seen here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/project-tool-window.html#file_status_highlight
2. You can see and change those colors at `Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Version Control | File Status Colors`
3. The IDE can mark the actual folders with colors as well. There is an option for that (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/30915650/783119 for details). These days it's located at `Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Version Control | Confirmation` screen and is called `Highlight directories that contain modified files in the Project tree`.

   The colors that will be used here (so you can change them if needed): `Have changed descendants` and `Have immediate changed children`.